# PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?

Tags: codeigniter, postgresql, sequence, postgresql-9.1, nextval

I am using PostgreSQL for my Codeigniter website. I am using grocery crud for add, edit and delete operations. While doing an edit or add, I want to rename an uploaded file dynamically based on the id of the content. I am able to do this using grocery crud's `callback_after_upload` function.

I want a next id of the content while adding a new content. I tried to use `nextval()` function, but sequence gets incremented with it. How can get the last value of the sequence without using `nextval()` function?

Or is there a simple way I can do this?

Comment: @saji89: Actually, this is outdated and needlessly inefficient, too. You can do this with *one* round-trip to the server. I added an answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It's still worth mentioning that, and mu's demo of a separate `nextval` call that's used in an insert, because unlike `INSERT ... RETURNING` both will work via query generation engines and other painful things that may not understand the `RETURNING` extension :S

Comment: @CraigRinger: If your query generator doesn't understand the `RETURNING` clause (which has been around for years now!), it may be outdated as well - or just a very poor crutch that's looking for replacement. Still, it's good to have the fallback solution a_horse provided. No argument there.

Answer (score 44):

#### `RETURNING`

That's possible with *a single round-trip* to the database:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(filename)
VALUES ('my_filename')
RETURNING tbl_id;
```

`tbl_id` would typically be a [**`serial`** or **`IDENTITY`** (Postgres 10 or later) column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860). [More in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

#### Explicitly fetch value

If `filename` needs to include `tbl_id` (redundantly), you can still use a single query.

Use [**`lastval()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) or the more specific [**`currval()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (filename)
VALUES ('my_filename' || currval('tbl_tbl_id_seq')   -- or lastval()
RETURNING tbl_id;
```

See:

- [Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433446#12433446)

If multiple sequences may be advanced in the process (even by way of triggers or other side effects) the *sure* way is to use `currval('tbl_tbl_id_seq')`.

#### Name of sequence

The *string literal* `'tbl_tbl_id_seq'` in my example is supposed to be the *actual* name of the sequence and is cast to `regclass`, which raises an exception if no sequence of that name can be found in the current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860).

`tbl_tbl_id_seq` is the automatically generated default for a table `tbl` with a serial column `tbl_id`. But there are no guarantees. A column default can fetch values from *any* sequence if so defined. And if the default name is taken when creating the table, Postgres picks the next free name according to a simple algorithm.

If you don't ***know*** the name of the sequence for a `serial` column, use the dedicated function [**`pg_get_serial_sequence()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE). Can be done on the fly:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (filename)
VALUES ('my_filename' || currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tbl', 'tbl_id'))
RETURNING tbl_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c853c6e9ee1124aae357ce9e503191e5)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a179/3)</sub>

Comment: But it doesn't help if you the generated value should be incorporated into the values being inserted. My understanding of "*so that I can dynamically name an uploaded file*" is that i_nomad wants put the generated ID into one of the values (filename) that is being inserted into the table. But the question is so terribly unclear that it's hard to say.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `tbl_id` is represented in the serial column anyway. But if you'd want to include it in the `filename`, you can do that, too. Added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 38):

The previously obtained value of a sequence is accessed with the `currval()` function.

But that will only return a value if `nextval()` has been called **before** that.

There is absolutely no way of "peeking" at the next value of a sequence without actually obtaining it.

But your question is unclear. If you call `nextval()` before doing the insert, you can use that value in the insert. Or even better, use `currval()` in your insert statement:

```
select nextval('my_sequence') ...

... do some stuff with the obtained value

insert into my_table(id, filename)
values (currval('my_sequence'), 'some_valid_filename');
```

Comment: I am using grocery crud for insert delete edit operations. I am using 'callback_after_upload' function for renaming a file. I am not passing id for insert.

Comment: @i_nomad: Where did this grocery thing come from suddenly? You asked a question about using sequences in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, it is about using sequences in PostgreSQL and I was just explaining what I am trying to do with the 'nextval' of sequence.

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled upon this question b/c I was trying to find the next sequence value by table. This didn't answer my question however this is how its done, and it may help those looking for the sequence value not by name but by table:

```
SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('<your_table>', 'id')) AS new_id;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 9):

## Answer for 2022

You can use [pg_sequence_last_value()](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/06/14/scalable-incremental-data-aggregation/) if you know the name of the sequence:

```
SELECT pg_sequence_last_value('public.person_id_seq');
```

Comment: That's not a PostgreSQL function.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAAaqYe_YXrkpLb2xZ0Vxi9hNnwn6tDeE3XAHw1YN8boBjaNX4Q%40mail.gmail.com#fabb846529213ba918c6d7554c962798  @a_horse_with_no_name it is....

Comment: hi. the link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

If your are not in a session you can just nextval('you_sequence_name') and it's just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question literally, here's how to get the next value of a sequence without incrementing it:

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN is_called THEN
   last_value + 1
 ELSE
   last_value
 END
FROM sequence_name
```

Obviously, it is not a good idea to use this code in practice. **There is no guarantee that the next row will really have this ID.** However, for debugging purposes it might be interesting to know the value of a sequence without incrementing it, and this is how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works perfectly

```
@Entity
public class Shipwreck {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "shipwreck_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  Long id;
```

....

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.shipwreck_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 110
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

Even if this can somehow be done it is a terrible idea since it would be possible to get a sequence that then gets used by another record!

A much better idea is to save the record and then retrieve the sequence afterwards.

Comment: That's not true. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-sequence.html