# How to get the ID of a previously inserted row within a transaction using QSqlQuery

Tags: qt, transactions, qtsql

I am trying to get the primary key of an inserted row within a transaction scope, because I do not want to leave the db in a logically inconsistent state.

My problem is I cannot find a way to retrieve the ID value of a previously executed query, which I want to use for the next insert query. Querying the PostgreSQL database while the transaction is in effect shows no results in the non-foreign-key table(the row is not yet committed?). I believe this is due to the transaction's isolation level.

Below is what I'm trying to do with production code, albeit slightly edited and narrowed down to one function for clarity. `const int lastInsertId` is always 0, which in this  context should mean no value was found (technically that `toInt()` function failed). I tried manually inserting a valid non-foreign-key row, and then calling `LASTVAL()` which produced the expected result - the ID of the inserted row.

So, what am I doing wrong? What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

```
void createEntityWithoutForiegnKeyConstraint(const QString &nameOfEntity)
{
  db_.transaction();

  QSqlQuery insertQuery(db_);
  insertQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO \"EntityWithoutForeignKey\" (\"name\") VALUES (:name);");

  insertQuery.bindValue(":name", nameOfEntity);
  execQuery(__LINE__, insertQuery);
  QSqlQuery lastIdQuery("SELECT LASTVAL();", db_); // auto executes
  const int lastInsertId = lastIdQuery.value(0).toInt();

  if (lastInsertId <= 0) // 0 is not a valid ID
    throw exception("Oh noes.");

  createEntityWithForeignKeyConstraint(lastInsertId, someData);

  if (!db_.commit())
    db_.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences

Comment: Agreed; `INSERT ... RETURNING` is ideal here. See the [`INSERT` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) for specifics.

Comment: Confirmed that RETURNING works from pgAdmin for a test insert, like so `INSERT INTO nonforeignkeyentity ("id", "name") VALUES (DEFAULT, 'teste') RETURNING "id"`. But this does not work via `QSqlQuery`, so I am still in need of guidance here. How to retrieve that value from the query object. Must I bind a variable for the return value or something?

Comment: `insertQuery.record().indexOf("id");` returns 0, which is a valid index according to the Qt documentation. I am really flustered. If the field exists, why is there no value there?

Comment: You probably have to call insertQuery.next() before fetching the value .

Comment: Doh! You're absolutely right. Don't know what should be judged answer here, since there are no answers. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but in Qt 5.10 (and likely earlier) there is a function `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()` which can be called after `QSqlQuery::exec()`.

It's quite useful if you are using a database such as SQLite which doesn't support the `RETURNING` clause on an `INSERT` statement.

[QSqlQuery::lastInsertId() documentation.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId)

Usage is something along the lines of the following:

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.prepare("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(:some_column_name)");
q.bindValue(":some_column_name", "FooBar");
q.exec();

qDebug() << "Last ID was:" << q.lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kasheen is perfectly right but I want to set the focus on one important aspect you should keep in mind: **Don't forget to encapsulate everything in one single transaction**.

Why? It saves time and avoids database corruption if the second insert using the generated primary key (you got with `q.lastInsertId()`) fails.

So your insert should look like this (this is basically @Kasheen's answer with some additions):

```
db_.transaction(); // Starts a transaction

QSqlQuery q;

// first insert
q.prepare("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(:some_column_name)");
q.bindValue(":some_column_name", "FooBar");
q.exec();

auto pk == q.lastInsertId().toInt;

// second insert
q.prepare("INSERT INTO other_table VALUES(:other_column_name, :fk)");
q.bindValue(":other_column_name", "OtherText");
q.bindValue(":fk", pk);
q.exec();

db_.commit(); // Commits transaction
```

@average joe does the transaction handling correctly but you might forget it if you look on the solution only.