# Get the ID of inserted rows from QSqlQuery

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qsqlquery

I am using QSqlQuery to insert multiple entries in one query. I need to get the IDs of all elements that were inserted with my query :

```
QString queryContent = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES";
bool insertedFirstEntry = false;
for (const auto& data : dataCollection)
{
    if (insertedFirstEntry)
        queryContent += ",";
    else
        insertedFirstEntry = true;

    queryContent += QString(" ('%1', '%2')").arg(data.field1).arg(data.field2);
}

QSqlQuery query(db);
const bool result = query.exec(queryContent);

std::vector<int> insertedIds;
if (result)
{
    while (query.next())
        insertedIds.push_back(query.value(0).toInt());
}
return insertedIds;
```

This code is not working as query.next() is always returning false.

[Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#value) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802614/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-previously-inserted-row-within-a-transaction-using-qsqlqu) suggests using `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()`, but as I have multiple entries that have been inserted, this wouldn't work for my use case.

Also, Qt documentation warns that `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()` is to be used only for the case of single record inserts :

> Returns the object ID of the most recent inserted row if the database
> supports it. An invalid QVariant will be returned if the query did not
> insert any value or if the database does not report the id back. **If
> more than one row was touched by the insert, the behavior is
> undefined**.

**How can I retrieve the ids of all entries that have been inserted by my query?**

Comment: I know you don't really need a scolding right now, but this is one reason why AUTOINCREMENT fields are less than optimal.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain what you would do / organize the database in an answer?

Comment: Well, the principle is that, if you need to KNOW the unique ID of the row, then you should assign a unique ID in the columns you are adding -- your own primary key.  It's a little late to make that change now.