# How to increment id by X in Postgres using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How can I increment this id, by 4 instead of 1 as it does by default using SQLAlchemy + Postgres? I'm using SQLAlchemy, Postgres, and Alembic.

```
id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the name of the underlying `SEQUENCE` for your [`serial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788) column and change its increment:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('tbl', 'id');
```

Then:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tbl_id_seq INCREMENT 4;  -- replace with actual name
```

*Or* with a single integrated [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
EXECUTE format('ALTER SEQUENCE %s INCREMENT 4'
              , pg_get_serial_sequence('tbl', 'id');
END$$;
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences/13394177#13394177)

Comment: That's using postgres. I'd ideally like something that works with SQLAlchemy/Alembic

Comment: As a temporary solution I am manually running this and it works