# Is it possible to create two tables with disjoint identifiers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, primary-key, create-table

By "disjoint" I mean mutually exclusive sets of ID values. No overlap between both tables.
For example, the sequence generator for the `id` column on both tables should work in conjunction to make sure they are always disjoint. I am not sure if this is possible. So, I thought I would just ask here.

Table A

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | abc |
| 1 | cad |
| 2 | pad |
| 3 | ial |

Table B

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | pal |
| 50 | sal |

Comment: So you're using `SERIAL` in both tables?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: Then you can't do it like that, because that's how `SERIAL` works. To what extent can you redesign your database? If the values come from **two separate** `SERIAL` columns then you cannot prevent them from ever possibly having the same value. There is a solution to this problem which requires using a third table, however.

Comment: I think I can accommodate a third table. How would that solution look like?

Comment: The only clean solution is: remodel your data.  This could imply a third table. This ugly problem should not exist.

Answer (score 4):

A different hack-around:

---

```
CREATE TABLE odd(
        id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START 1 INCREMENT 2)
        , val integer
        );


CREATE TABLE even(
        id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START 2 INCREMENT 2)
        , val integer
        );

INSERT INTO odd (val)
SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(1,10);

INSERT INTO even (val)
SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(1,20);

SELECT * FROM odd;
SELECT * FROM even;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
INSERT 0 20
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  3 |   2
  5 |   3
  7 |   4
  9 |   5
 11 |   6
 13 |   7
 15 |   8
 17 |   9
 19 |  10
(10 rows)

 id | val 
----+-----
  2 |   1
  4 |   2
  6 |   3
  8 |   4
 10 |   5
 12 |   6
 14 |   7
 16 |   8
 18 |   9
 20 |  10
 22 |  11
 24 |  12
 26 |  13
 28 |  14
 30 |  15
 32 |  16
 34 |  17
 36 |  18
 38 |  19
 40 |  20
(20 rows)
```

Comment: Clever! You can make this resilient by adding a `CHECK` constraint to ensure numbers are `MOD 2` or `MOD 2 + 1` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way is to share the same [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, name text
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
, name text
);

SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('a', 'id');  -- 'public.a_id_seq'

ALTER TABLE b ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.a_id_seq');  -- !
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=014bb1095c653b19f9422e6688391144)*

This way, table `a` "owns" the sequence, while table `b` draws from the same source. You can also create an independent `SEQUENCE` if you prefer.

**Note:** this **only** guarantees mutually exclusive new IDs (even under concurrent write load) while you don't override default values and also don't update them later.

Related:

- [Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657693/creating-a-postgresql-sequence-to-a-field-which-is-not-the-id-of-the-record/24659884#24659884)
- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-rename-tables-using-serial-primary-key-columns/14651788#14651788)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)
- [PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences/13394177#13394177)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the painful world of inter-table constraints or assertions - this is something that ISO SQL and pretty much every RDBMS out there does not handle ergonomically...

(While ISO SQL *does* describe both deferred-constraints and database-wide assertions, as far as I know only PostgreSQL implements deferred-constraints, and no production-quality RDBMS supports database-wide assertions).

---

One approach is to have a third-table which is the *only* table with `SERIAL` (aka `IDENTITY` aka `AUTO_INCREMENT`) with a discriminator column which combined forms the table's primary-key, then the other two tables have an FK constraint to that PK - but they'll also need the same discriminator column (enforced with a `CHECK` constraint), but you will never need to reference that column in most queries.

As your post doesn't tell us what the *real* table-names are, I'll use my own.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE postIds (
    postId   int     NOT NULL SERIAL,
    postType char(1) NOT NULL, /* This is the discriminator column. It can only contain ONLY either 'S' or 'G' which indicates which table contains the rest of the data */

    CONSTRAINT PK_postIds PRIMARY KEY ( postId, postType ),
    CONSTRAINT CK_type CHECK ( postType IN ( 'S', 'G' ) )
);

CREATE TABLE shitposts (
    postId   int     NOT NULL,
    postType char(1) DEFAULT('S'),

    foobar   nvarchar(255)     NULL,
    etc      int           NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_shitpostIds PRIMARY KEY ( postId, postType ),
    CONSTRAINT CK_type CHECK ( postType = 'S' ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_shitpost_ids FOREIGN KEY ( postId, postType ) REFERENCES postIds ( postId, postType )
);

CREATE TABLE goldposts (
    postId   int     NOT NULL,
    postType char(1) DEFAULT('G'),

    foobar   nvarchar(255)     NULL,
    etc      int           NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_goldpostIds PRIMARY KEY ( postId, postType ),
    CONSTRAINT CK_type CHECK ( postType = 'G' ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_goldpost_ids FOREIGN KEY ( postId, postType ) REFERENCES postIds ( postId, postType )
)
```

With this design, it is impossible for any row in `shitposts` to share a `postId` value with a post in `goldposts` and vice-versa.

However it *is* possible for a row to exist in `postIds` *without* having any row in both `goldposts` and `shitposts`. Fortunately, as you are using PostgreSQL you *could* add a new FK constraint from `postIds` to both `goldposts` and `shitposts` but use it with deferred-constraints.

Comment: There is no `nvarchar` in Postgres. And I'd consider `"char"` (with quotes) instead of `char(1)`. (Never use the type `char`) And set `postType` to `NOT NULL` or the multicolumn FK can be sidestepped with default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior - see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684. Other than that, it's a good (if tedious) solution!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, thank you for pointing that out - I mostly work in T-SQL instead of Postgres so my T-SQLisms slip through.

Comment: Aside: `SERIAL` and `IDENTITY` are related but separate concepts in Postgres. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This thread says that they’re the same concept/feature, but IDENTITY is ISO-compliant and SERIAL is legacy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300370/postgresql-serial-vs-identity