# Splitting a postgres SQL insert statement into 2 tables using triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-insert

Is it possible to use postgres triggers to split an INSERT statement into 2 tables? So if you do `insert into testtable (col1, col2) values (val1a, val1b), (val2a, val2b)`, can it be translated with triggers to something like

```
insert into testtable (col1) values (val1a), (val1b)
insert into anothertable (col2) values (val2a), (val2b)
```

Basically is it possible for `testtable` to not have a `col2` even though the original SQL INSERT looks like `col2` should exist on `testtable`?

How can this be accomplished using triggers?

Comment: I suspect you mean `insert into firsttable (col1) values (val1a), (val2a);
insert into secondtable (col2) values (val1b), (val2b)` ...

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `VIEW` with either triggers or rules to redirect the `INSERT`.

- [INSERT ...RETURNING .. comes up empty when BEFORE trigger cancels statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046173/insert-returning-comes-up-empty-when-before-trigger-cancels-statement/24049302#24049302)

Or you can do it in a single SQL statement with data-modifying CTEs.

```
WITH input(col1, col2) AS (
   VALUES
     (text 'val1a', text 'val1b')  --  explicit type cast in first row
   , ('val2a', 'val2b')
   )
, ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO testtable (col1)
   SELECT col1 FROM input
   )
INSERT INTO anothertable (col2)
SELECT col2 FROM input;
```

Typically, one would also store the connections between 'val1a' and 'val1b' of your input row *somehow*.
You might want to use a `RETURNING` clause to get a serial PK from the first table and store that in the second table.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)
- [Combining INSERT statements in a data-modifying CTE with a CASE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992241/combining-insert-statements-in-a-data-modifying-cte-with-a-case-expression/28993466#28993466)
- [INSERT rows into multiple tables in a single query, selecting from an involved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t/10472136#10472136)

Comment: I'm interested in the RULE method in the page you linked to, but you say rules can be tricky. I read the page you suggested to read there but I'm not sure about a few things. If the rule has a few different statements in an INSTEAD clause, are all those statements executed transactionally? So if one fails they all fail?

Comment: @user779159: Yes. If *anything* inside the same transaction raises an exception, the *whole* transaction is rolled back. RULEs are *always* atomic for any number of statements.